# bcp (Boost) to copy a minimal subset library dependency

Tags: c++, regex, boost, subset

I am currently trying to copy a subset of regex (also known as regular expressions) library and its dependencies so I can bring it to school to work with. I could be using Microsoft's regular expressions from the C++11 standard library, but my school's computers do not support the C++11 library.

Anyways, to make this possible, I have compiled the bcp tool successfully and I have typed
`bcp boost/regex.hpp <my destination folder>` on my command prompt window.

The problem is that I get the following error:

```
**** exception(205): std::runtime_error: Found a closing ) with no corresponding openening parenthesis.  The error occurred while parsing the regular expression fragment: "?+(([(<].*HERE>>>)?$)?".
```

Any kind of advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Very peculiar.  The quoted code has an OPENING ( with no corresponding closing parenthesis.  Try escaping the open parenthesis with a slosh \:

```
"?+(([\(<].*HERE>>>)?$)?"
```

This would not alter the regular expression, but may help the parser.

Comment: It may help if we can see the entire line where the code failed, not just the fragment.

Comment: I would love to provide the entire line, but that is actually the only fragment of the error I received.. By the way, I am having trouble with locating the actual file that has "?+(([\(<].*HERE>>>)?$)?" in them. Any hints?

Comment: Try looking at [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-finding-files-by-content/) tutorial.  All I can say is that this is a very useful Terminal tool to memorize and have at your disposal.

Comment: I don't think grep method will work since in my opinion, `"?+(([(<].*HERE>>>)?$)?"` is found in one of many many dependencies of regex.hpp